# Rake, Active Record - Rails rake task, update record in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a rake task wich should update a record in the database but to no avail. Does it work diffirently when calling from rake?

here is what I have, it runs without an error, but it does not update the record in the db

```
task :remove_vintage_from_slugs => :environment do
 wine = Wine.find_by_id(22)
 wine.slug = "new value"
 wine.save
end
```

### Update

wine.save! returns true?

1.9.2-p318 :001 > wine = Wine.find_by_id(23)
1.9.2-p318 :002 > wine.slug = "test"
1.9.2-p318 :003 > wine.save!
 => true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. By default, save always run validations. If any of them fail the action is cancelled and save returns false. However, if you supply :validate => false, validations are bypassed altogether.
2. There’s a series of callbacks associated with save. If any of the before_* callbacks return false the action is cancelled and save returns false.

Check to see whether the save is returning false for some reason in the console. Better still you should use save! (with a bang). With save! validations always run. If any of them fail ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid gets raised.

Comment: ah yes, seems it a problem with validations somewhere, how do I go about debugging it, do I run save! in console?

Comment: Yes. @obj.errors.full_messages will tell you what validations failed.

Comment: one last thing, when I run .save! in console, it does not update the db? but returns true, is this expected behaviour?

Comment: No. If it returns true, the record must have been saved. How are you checking the values in the DB. If from console, do wine.reload!.

Comment: Also, there's a series of callbacks associated with save!. If any of the before_* callbacks return false the action is cancelled and save! raises ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19567/discussion-between-francois-and-syed-aslam)